# Android. Changing fragment defined in xml

Tags: android, xml, fragment

Is it possible to change fragment defined i xml?

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

A have a lot of screens to show and switch. A tab-like menu on the right. Every tab have another tabs. I want to simply change this one by one. Maybe someone have better idea?

**SOLVED**

I used ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

```
private ViewPager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_content);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ControllerFragment cf = new ControllerFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), getFragment());
    pager.setAdapter(cf);
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
    list.add(fragment);

    return list;
}

public void onTabSelected(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ivProfile:
            pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
}

public class ControllerFragment extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> fragments;

public ControllerFragment(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments){
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0){
    return this.fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Do it at runtime using fragment calss load that fragment in frame layout.

Comment: @Khizar Hayat How? fragment = (Fragment) findViewById(R.id.fragment); is an error

Comment: no it is not the way.

Comment: @Khizar Hayat  i get a solution :)